# Get number of combinatory complementary repeating

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

What is the number of combined elements without combining a number with it's complement?

Example:
Suppose I have $n = 3$ elements and their respective complements.

$A, B, C, A', B', C'$

So, my actual $n$, let's say, $m = 6$.

Let's say, for $p = 2$:

$\complement_2^6 = \frac{6!}{2!(6-2)!} = 15$

Gives me this set:

$AB, AC, BC, A'B', A'C',B'C', AB', AC', BC', BA', CA', CB'$
and, the complement-combined: $AA', BB', CC'$.

In other words, I want to know the formula that gives me the length of the first or second set, given any $n$ and $p$.

For $n = 3$ (then $m = 6$) and $p = 1$ the repeated set will be of length $0$, for $p = 3$ this length is $12$.

Comment: Let me try to this straight and check that I understand your question by rewording it slightly... you have a total of, say, $2n$ distinguishable objects, each of which is paired with another, for example $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,\dots,n_1,n_2$.  You are asking how many ways we can select $p$ of these objects simultaneously (i.e. order of selection doesn't matter) such that no object appears in the same selection as it's paired object?

Comment: @JMoravitz exactly. I apologize for my bad communicability.

Comment: If so, then use multiplication principle.  There are $\binom{n}{p}$ ways to choose which $p$ of the "letters" appeared, and then $2$ options for the subscript of each letter.  There are then $\binom{n}{p}2^p$ different options.  In the case of $n=3,p=2$ this would be $\binom{3}{2}2^2=3\cdot 4=12$.  It sounds as though you are interested in the number of selections where you have at least one letter appearing alongside its pair as well, in which case just subtract away from $\binom{2n}{p}$ to get $\binom{2n}{p}-\binom{n}{p}2^p$.

Comment: @JMoravitz submit an answer so I can accept